# Why did Driscoll say, "One flash behind you"?

Tags: dialogue, spenser-confidential-2020

In *Spenser Confidential (2020)*, Globe journalist Wayne, shows Spenser CCTV footage from a convenience store that details
Gloria Weisnewski’s murder. Wayne admitted that Globe put him on another story and
is avoiding Gloria's murder.

> Spenser: So what're they hiding?
>
> Wayne: I was hoping you could tell me that. This is fucked up, man.
> Tracksuit must have put them on it.
>
> Spenser: Fuckin' Boylan.

Spenser recalls the incident where he and Driscoll were sitting in the parked police
car near Captain Boylan's house with no police cars around.

> Driscoll: Hey, one flash behind. **One flash behind you**, baby.

Spenser gets down from the car, walks around Captain Boylan's house, and knocks on Captain Boylan's house door. Boylan answers it. I know flash refers to "cops flash their side lights".

Why did Driscoll say, "One flash behind you"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's from car driver slang, which means "give way to me, I'm going faster than you". In our case, it could mean, "Let the situation go" or "Be kind".

Comment: Welcome to Movies StackExchange! Your answer will add to our collective knowledge! One suggestion I can think of is to provide a source in a block quote. It can show where the curious can learn more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome @buggy_bug! Lots of good answers on this site have no citations, so don't worry too much about that: https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/2395/96544; https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/28347/96544; https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/87944/96544

Comment: Also, I read this: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/413/96544 it says to make it clear your answer is a guess, which you do.